# Getting Emacs indentation to work correctly in major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode

I am writing a major-mode in emacs for a DSL I've created. I'm inheriting from fundamental-mode, which tabs out way far (6 tab stops, I think).

I'd like to be able to define:

```
(setq mydsl-tab-width 4)
```

and have that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite understanding the question...

In your major mode, I presume you're making some settings.  Perhaps one of those could be:

```
(setq tab-width mydsl-tab-width)  ;# use the tab width specified by your variable
```

Could you elaborate on how `mydsl-tab-width` is currently used?  Emacs surely doesn't know about it - `tab-width` is the variable to use/set.

Comment: Ah - that works. I wasn't sure how that interconnected. There's some interesting magic related to modes and autogeneratation, I've noticed.